# I cannot log into meta while using HTTPS-Everywhere in Firefox

Tags: support, ssl

I am running the latest version of HTTPS Everywhere for Firefox. See website here: https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere .

I'm using Firefox 25.0.1 on Kubuntu 12.04.

If HTTPS Everywhere is active, I cannot log into http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com . If I disable the extension I can log in. Obviously, I prefer to keep the extension active. I have never had issues at any other sites other than meta.*.stackexchange.com.

This makes me much less inclined to log in and participate in meta discussions because there is a barrier to doing so (and that barrier involves restarting my browser).

Maybe a greasemonkey script or something would solve this??? (I have no idea...)

Comment: Doesn't HTTPS Everywhere have a whitelist/blacklist facility where you can disable it on certain sites? I found these directions on making your own rulesets: https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/rulesets

Comment: HTTPS Everywhere recently added all of Stack Exchange to its default whitelist, but HTTPS isn't officially supported yet and does not work fully. Meta sites are one of the things that don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't HTTPS Everywhere have a whitelist/blacklist facility where you can disable it on certain sites? I found these directions on making your own rulesets: [HTTPS Everywhere Rulesets](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/rulesets).

Though I agree with you it would be best if you didn't need to workaround this. I think your request is apt.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that HTTPS Everywhere causes login issues; I'm not sure exactly what it's caused by. I've seen it happen on meta.*.stackexchange.com sites, as well as chat.stackexchange.com. It happens on Windows (Firefox 26, Windows 7), Mac OS X (Firefox Nightly, built within the last 2 weeks as of 1/14/14), and Arch GNU/Linux (updated recently, Firefox 26).

This is a problem with the extension rulesets, not with Stack Exchange. I've been meaning to report it; if you do, please let us know so that we can make sure to not do the same thing.

Comment: It would be great it you report it. It sounds like you have a little more detail about the sites affected than I do.