# Is it possible to keep stackexchange sites from redirecting out of SSL (https)?

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange, ssl

Like user [Gilles](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) mentions in a comment [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2655/i-cannot-log-into-meta-while-using-https-everywhere-in-firefox/2660#comment2528_2655),
"HTTPS isn't officially supported yet and does not work fully".

Is that still the case?  Every page I visit seems to work with https, but I often have to prepend `https://` to the link URLs manually, after the site tries to redirect me to a non-ssl page.  I would suggest to update the links throughout all the sites so that if one is connected with https, they stay there.  I make this suggestion with all due respect that the sites are awesome, and that it may not be a simple, easy task; just pointing it out!

I don't have enough points yet in the meta site to answer several questions about HttpsEverywhere;  but it seems like their problems are not the whitelist, or any other plugin, but that the links on Stackexchange forums don't correctly link back to https.

Comment: This also makes plugins like _noscript_ also throw lots of fits: once the same script tries to come over http (instead of https) it is blocked, and as well if you connect via http, then it forgets that you had 'allowed' the https scripts--nasty!

Comment: Which links are you talking about? All the links I've seen **inside one site** link back to HTTPS. Cross-site links are to HTTP all over. Note that meta sites don't work over HTTPS (the rest does work for me now). Links in posts and comments are of course whatever the author posted.

Comment: @Gilles What I'd really like to see would be that if somebody logs in from <https://stackexchange.com>, (and for example the scripts running from _https://stackauth.com_), then they wouldn't get redirected from that point to non-ssl connections, or even have to login again for all the sites from the Stackexchange family.  Just now, to read your comment, I was redirected twice out of ssl; from the stackauch pop-up, and then again when I clicked "login" (even though I had just logged in).

Comment: has this all finally been fixed by now?

Comment: I have same problem. My site doesn't establishe a https connection with stackexchange. Do you have any solution?

Comment: > As per Nick Craver's blog post about getting Stack Exchange onto SSL, it is currently impossible for them to get SSL working on the meta sites, because wildcard certs of the form 'meta.*.stackexchange.com' won't work.